# Advantages of razor replace (@href)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In the documentation of ASP.NET MVC says that you should do something like this when have a link in a view

```
<a href="@href("~/SubPage")">Subpage</a>.
```

The razor engine replaces `@href("~/SubPage")`to `/Subpage`.

What is the advantage of do it this way instead

```
<a href="/SubPage">Subpage</a>.
```

In cases like this and in others (like creating a form) why use the razor engine instead of write directly what you want. I think is faster on the server side to print something directly that let the engine to generate it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your application runs in a subfolder, the Razor @href will create the correct link like this:

```
www.myapp.com/subfolder/SubPage
```

If you write it by yourself your link will be like this and will not work:

```
www.myapp.com/SubPage
```

Thats because `~` will be replaced with your application root by Razor.

Comment: And if I write the link right with the subfolder or the app is not in a subfolder, is there any advantages?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But you loose flexibility - you are never able to change the name of the subfolder without searching your whole project where you wrote down that name. I highly disadvise to do that.

Comment: +1- this little gem (@href) is SOO overlooked by many devs (when not using @Html.ActionLink()). would give you a double vote if i could :)

Answer (score 2):

The `ActionLink` method cannot take `HTML`.

You need to make a normal `<a>` tag, and use `@Url.Action(...)` for the `href`.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")">Link Text</a>.
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply write

`<a href="SubPage">Subpage</a>`

I can't realize any negative fallback

Comment: If you have defined custom routes, this would potentially break links. For example, if I have a custom route `a/b/c` mapped to the `SubPage` action of the `PageController` and my link href is `OtherPage`, the browser will navigate to `a/b/OtherPage` though, in this context, the intended target would likely be `Page/OtherPage`. This isn't just about how your app is currently written, it's about writing every app in a way that is adaptive and can degrade gracefully. This makes the app a bit more portable and also more readily supports future changes.